# {} as replacement key in Python new-style formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can use special characters in keyword arguments for formatting strings (evaluates to `"123"`):

```
"{()}".format(**{"()": 123})
```

But then, understandably, this doesn't work (evaluates to `"{}"` as documented):

```
"{{}}".format(**{"{}": 123})
```

**Is there a way to use `{}` as replacement key using Python new-style formatting?**

I am specifically looking for solutions that use Python's new-style formatting. This is an academic question, not something I really want or need.

Comment: Your first example doesn't really contradict the docs. `"()"` is the "keyword" defined by the dict you unpack in the call to `format`.

Comment: You're right, I'll remove this part of the question.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this question is too broad.

Comment: I'm not too sure either, since you already stated your intentions at the end.

Comment: Interestingly, this works: `'{ {}}'.format(**{' {}': 123})`

Comment: Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings): "Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string."